How to create an authorized redirect URL to register a website application for Google Cloud
I'm currently having trouble with Google Sheets as my students keep increasing, and I have to manage their homework account from another platform, and on Google Classroom in Google Sheets. It's too long, complicated, and time consuming. Thus, I'm trying to make a website or webapp so that I can shorten this process. Currently I'm going through my first phase, which is import my Google Sheets to MySQL database, which is where my problem occured.
I searched a YouTube tutorial to import Google Sheets to a database by python with the help of Google Cloud API. However, after I tried and run my code, Google said "Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid".
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc as odbc

from Google import Create_Service #nhập Create_service từ google

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
API_NAME = 'sheets'
API_VERSION = 'v4'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

google_sheets_id = '1G7hwo9YJXuDZIUeOQmxxqrsEMv4QvNd11K15Ng4zjhA'

response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
    spreadsheetId = google_sheets_id,
    majorDimension = 'ROWS',
    range = 'Lớp 12'
).execute()

After that, I searched for a reason why it couldn't run. I read Google documents of authorization, and found out that I needed an authorized redirect URL. So I tried to test with http://localhost:8080 in the document, still invalid. I went to watch some other YouTube videos about the redirect URL which also didn't work. Then I thought why not made a personal DNS from my local IP or create a domain, I tried and follow their instructions, but Google still endup saying it was invalid. Furthermore, I couldn't find any instruction I could read nor follow. Some do help me create a free domain, but still Google said it was invalid. Thus, I searched again for about a week for any sources could help me with it, and I resulted in a deadend.
